# Short Kloosterman sum

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory

Let $K(m,n,c)=\sum_{p\in A}\exp(2\pi i(pm+np^{-1}))$, where $m,n\in\mathbb{Z}$, $c\in\mathbb{N}$, and $A\subset (\mathbb{Z}/c\mathbb{Z})^\times$.

Does anybody know any nontrivial bound for this kind of sum. More precisely, is it true that $K(m,n,c)\ll c^{1/2}$?

Thanks.

ADD: Sorry for replying too late. My set $A$ has property that there is $K\in (Z/cZ)*$ such that if $p\in A$ and $(K-p,c)=1$ then $K-p \in A$. This is a kind of symmetry around $K$. Furthermore, $|A|\geq c^{1/2}$.

Comment: What kind of set is $A$?  If $A$ is arbitrary then the sum can be of the order of $c$, just by using the pigeonhole principle to locate a quadrant that contains a lot of the summands $e(pm + np^{-1})$, and setting $A$ to be all the $p$ whose summand lies in that quadrant.

Comment: That additional information on $A$ is not enough, a slight variant of Terry's argument still works to provide a counterexample to any nontrivial bound.